# Flutter- using fastlane with android multi flavors

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, fastlane, gradlew

I am using Flutter with multi flavors. And I'm trying to automate the building of apk. I declared this lane:

```
lane:
  desc "build apk"
  lane :test_build_android_app do |options|
    gradle(task: "assembleProductionfirst", build_type: "Release" })
  end
```

when I run this lane, I get this error:

> Compiler message: Error: Error when reading 'lib/main.dart': No such
>   file or directory package:flutter_app/main.dart: Error: No 'main'
>   method found. Try adding a method named 'main' to your program. Target
>   kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation:
>   null build failed.

I have several mains. So I need to run `flutter build -t lib/first/main.dart`

How can specify the flutter main path when using `fastlane` or `gradlew`?

Comment: What OS are you using? and are you trying to use a CI platform? and are you using the command from the root of your folder's project?

Comment: Linux OpenSuse, Jenkins

Comment: can you post your 'lib/first/main.dart' ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had the same issue - using "flags" did the trick for me:

> gradle(
>        flavor: "my_flavor",
>        task: "bundle",
>        build_type: "Release",
>        flags: "-Ptarget=lib/main_flavor.dart")

Comment: Can we do the same for fastlane's `gym` lane for iOS?

Comment: @RohanTaneja for IOS you can combine "scheme" and "configuration"

Comment: Love you man! Using Gradle flags are indeed the way to go. Here you can find all gradle related actions: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/gradle/

Comment: its not working,