# Flutter- fastlane with iOS multi flavors

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, fastlane, cicd

I am using Flutter with multiple flavors. I am using fastlane to automate the iOS build like below, I have multiple flavours and I have multiple main.dart variants respectively:

```
private_lane :build4iOS do |options|
 
  build_app(
      workspace: "./#{$project_name}.xcworkspace",
      configuration: myConfiguration,
      scheme: myScheme,
      silent: false,
      clean: true,
      export_options:{ manageAppVersionAndBuildNumber: false, method: options[:export_options] }
  )
```

This works perfectly fine for android as I am passing the flags: "-Ptarget=lib/main_flavor.dart" to the build cradle function as per the answer to this question: [Flutter- using fastlane with android multi flavors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59859177/flutter-using-fastlane-with-android-multi-flavors).

However for iOS I don't know how to pass the same flag in the build_app action! All the build types pick up the same variant of main.dart

How can I set such a flag so the iOS build also points to the correct variant of main-flavour.dart

I went through the documents but could not find a sulotion also can not find any solution for this on stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this as well. The best solution I could find was to update the `FLUTTER_TARGET` variable in XCode to match all the flavors.

1. Open up XCode by double clicking `ios/Runner.xcworkspace`
2. Click on Runner > Build Settings
3. Type "FLUTTER_TARGET" into the search bar and expand the `FLUTTER_TARGET` variable in that list
4. Proceed to rename all the `main.dart` to match your flavors.

Answer (score 0):

Config `FLUTTER_TARGET` variable like photo below, then when building (XCode or CICD like FastLane) you just need to care about scheme (Dev, Staging, Prod... as usual), and it auto pick up the right file .dart entry point

[image]